# Update scope from a directive on mousedown Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having an issue updating the scope in a controller from a directive. Below are the basics of what is going on.

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', ['$document', function($document) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
            angular.element(element).bind('mousedown', function(event){
                scope.name = 'test';
            });
        }
    }
}


myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'something';
}]);
```

The html:

```
<p>{{name}}</p>
<p my-directive>Click me</p>
```

The result above is always `something` that was set in my controller, and is never updated to `test`.

I have tried a `$watch` in my controller but it never updates, so i have to be just missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery `.bind` functionality you have to use `scope.$apply` to notify Angular that you have updated a scope property.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element(element).bind('mousedown', function(event) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.name = 'test';
          });
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'something';
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <p>{{name}}</p>
  <p my-directive>Click Me</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Directives have their own isolated scope.  If you want to share something between a directive's scope and a controller's scope, you need to include it in the directive definition like this:

```
return {
    scope: {
        name: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
        angular.element(element).bind('mousedown', function(event){
            scope.name = 'test';
        });
    }
}
```

This tells Angular that you want to share the scope variable `name` between the directive and whatever scope calls that directive.  Using the equal sign (=) defines it as two-way data binding.

Comment: Directives only have isolate scope if you create it using the `scope` property as you have shown. Otherwise they inherit the parent scope through prototypal inheritance.

Comment: Good point.  And you noticed something I missed in the OP's code: that he was trying to change the scope from a jQuery event function which needed the `scope.$apply` function.